# How to send Discord Messages over a period of seconds as opposed to instantly or make it seem like the bot is typing for a while

Tags: node.js, bots, discord.js

I have a discord bot that uses `Discord.js`. It can send messages instantly using code like

```
message.channel.send('hi')
```

This works just fine for sending normal messages but I would like to make it seem like it's taking a while to type (Not dissimilar to how the bot Chatty Cathy sends human-like messages).

[Check it out here](https://discord.gg/ppHxsX4)

How would I go about making a bot that also sends human time like messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `channel.startTyping()` and `channel.stopTyping()` to simulate time being taken for a message to send https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=startTyping. Something like:

```
channel.startTyping();
setTimeout(()=>{
    channel.send(string).then((message)=>{
        channel.stopTyping();
    });
}, 5000)
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Oh ok, sorry about that, I was looking for an accept button but had no idea where it was so I thought there wasn't one. Sorry again